# jQuery delay function interrupt

Tags: jquery, delay, interrupt

I have a pop-up window in jQuery that fades in, and will fade out in 10 seconds if not dismissed by the user.

I have the code:

```
$modalElement.fadeIn(1000).delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
```

And this works fine for the fade in, delay and fade out - but the `'close'` button on the form doesnt work until after the timeout!

I need the `'close'` button to interupt the `delay`, so that the user can read the pop up and close it themselves, say, at 5 seconds - and then if they havent closed it themselves, then it will close automatically after the 10 second delay.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: add the code for your close button - it should interrupt this code automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`.clearQueue()`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) method.

In your **close handler** you can do this:

```
$modalEleement.clearQueue();
```

By default, both [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [`.clearQueue()`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) operate on the `fx` queue, but you can pass custom queue names.

Comment: This does seem to work, and allows me to close the window before the delay - but it seems that the delay is still running in the background. For example, if I open the window and start the delay running, then close the window after 4 seconds, and then reopen the window after another 4 seconds, then the window will automatically close 2 seconds later - so the 10 second counter is obviously still running. Dont understand why that is!

Comment: I have now managed to get the overall effect working by using an animate function and the using the stop command to close the pop up. This seems to give the best overall performance so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a click event on the close button with a dequeue.

For example:

```
$modalElement.fadeIn(1000).delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);

$modalElement.find('a.close').click(function(){
  // If you want fadeout being triggerd
  $modalElement.dequeue() 
  // If you just want to delete the box without the fadeOut
  $modalElement.remove() 
});
```

Comment: Doing this will call anyway the `fadeOut` after ten seconds.