# How can I pause the .delay() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I am trying to create a toggle effect for the delay function

Click on function:

```
$('#swap').on('click', function(e){
//code bellow $('#swap').delay(1000).attr('src') == 'Play.png'
  if ($(this).attr('src') == 'Play.png') {
$('#swap').attr('src') == 'Pause.png'
}
else{
$('#swap').attr('src') == 'Play.png'
}
```

On click there starts a delay for another function:

```
$('#swap').delay(1000).attr('src') == 'Play.png'
```

And after that if you click on the `#swap` again the delay **pauses** *(Not stops)* and if you click again the delay then continues. Is this possible?

Because currently the delay would just start again from the beginning if clicked?

Comment: `delay` does only delay animations in the animation queue. You will need to use a callback instead.

Comment: Take a look on [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944830/jquery-delay-function-interrupt).

Comment: @GrzegorzŁuszczek That is a method I would use if I wanted to **stop** the delay rather than **pause** it.

Comment: You are probably going to have to build something yourself out of setTimeout and clearTimeout like l2aelba is going for. You need to keep track of the time passed when the delay was canceled, then start it back up again with the remaining time when you want to resume. You can store the timeout handle and the the elapsed time in a keyvalue pair in the element using the `data` method

Answer (score 1):

## .delay()

Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

*(ex : animations like fadeIn(), fadeOut(), .slideUp(), slideDown()... )*

**Doc :** http://api.jquery.com/delay/

---

**In your case , Try to use :**

```
setTimeout(function(){
 // Do something
},1000);
```

---

**If I understand, You mean somthing like this ..?**

```
var clicked;
$('#swap').on('click', function(e) {
    if(!clicked) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(this).attr('src','Play.png');
        },1000);
        clicked = true;
    } else {
         $(this).attr('src','Pause.png');
        clicked = false;
    }
});
```

---

Or use **toggle event**

```
$('#swap').toggle(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','Play.png');
  },1000);
},function() {
    $(this).attr('src','Pause.png');
});
```

**Doc :** http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

---

**Update :**

```
$('#swap').on('click',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var src = $this.attr('src');
    if (src == 'Play.png') {
        setTimeout(function(){
           $this.attr('src','Pause.png');
        },1000);
    } else {
        $this.attr('src','Play.png');
    }
});
```

---

**Update with clearTimeout() :**

```
var swapTimer;
$('#swap').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var src = $this.attr('src');
    if (src == 'Play.png') {
        swapTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            $this.attr('src', 'Pause.png');
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(swapTimer);
        $this.attr('src', 'Play.png');
    }
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/qnDh8/ (Play.png = red, Pause.png = yellow)

Comment: Good hint, but incomplete. The OP is going to need to be able to cancel timeouts as well to get the results they expect.

Comment: I have a `pause.png` and `play.png` that are creating a button. If the `play.png` is clicked - I want the delay function to start counting `1000` and for the image to swap to the `pause.png`. If the `pause.png` is then pressed I want the image to swap to the `play.png` and **Pause the delay** on what ever millisecond amount it is on, from the first click. And if you press the `play.png` for it to continue the delay function from the millisecond amount previous.

Comment: @l2aelba I have tried to make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FfuL/1/) But it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Seems like no point to cleartimeout(); when you want to cleartimeout ? @user2768038

Comment: @l2aelba I am not looking to delay the change to the `pause.png` I am looking to delay the `pause.png` going to the `play.png`

Comment: @l2aelba Like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout_cleartimeout2)